# traverse through multiple form values and put some of them inside struct slices

Tags: html, forms, go

I'm in a situation where I want to get an unknown number of input values into my Go structs, but only some of them will be placed inside a slice/array. Here's a snippet of the HTML content:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
...
<tbody>
    {{ range .users }}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
            <img class="avatar" src="{{ .AvatarThumbnailURL }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="thumbnail" value="{{ .AvatarThumbnailURL }}">
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ .Username }}<input type="hidden" name="username" value="{{ .Username }}">
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ .Age }}<input type="hidden" name="age" value="{{ .Age }}">
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ .Email }}<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ .Email }}">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="{{ .UserID }}">
    {{end}}
</tbody>
...
{{ .csrfField }}

// submit button

</form>
```

Where `{{ .csrfField }}` will generate a hidden input. This part is working fine.

Now the problem is how do I get this data inside a struct?

Let's say I have the following struct:

```
type UserFormData struct {
   UserID int
   Username string
   AvatarThumbnailURL string
   Age int
   Email string
}
```

But in my POST function I don't know how many users will be submitted through the form. So I guess I have to do something like this:

```
userFormData := make([]UserFormData, len(r.PostForm)/6)
```

(divided by 6 because there are AvatarThumbnailURL, Username, Age, Email, UserID and csrfField)

Then can go through the r.PostForm like this:

```
i := 0
j := 0
for key, values := range r.PostForm {
    switch key {
    case "userid":
        userid, _ := strconv.Atoi(values[0])
        userFormData[j].UserID = userid
    case "thumbnail":
        userFormData[j].Thumbnail = values[0]
    // the other fields
    i++
    if i%6 == 0 {
        j++
    }
}
```

While this work, it's extremely error prone to indexoutofrange and whenever I make a change then I have to count number of input values that will be sent with the form and update the (currently) '6' values. I have no doubt that there must be a much, much, much better way to do this, and I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction :)

Comment: There is probably a better way entirely, but this will at least avoid having to use magic numbers to know how many struct fields. https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.NumField

Comment: Question. If you are ranging over `.users`, then don't you know how many users will be submitted? Couldn't you include one more hidden field that includes how many users are on the form?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a browser will submit form fields in the order they appear in the HTML, so to be safe, you might want to append an identifier to the field names to make sure you can correctly associated related fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take use the fact that `r.PostForm` is actually a map where keys are the field names and values are an array of strings, so you can do something along these lines (I didn't test it, but the concept should work).

We iterate over all values for the `"userid"` field to know how many users there are. Also, you can use `append` to add users dynamically to the slice.

```
userFormData := []UserFormData{}
for i, userId := range r.PostForm["userid"] {
     user := UserFormData{
        UserID: userId,
        Thumbnail: r.PostForm["thumbnail"][i],
     }
     userFormData = append(userFormData, user)
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's great, seem to work perfectly, thanks a lot :) Does this method guarantee that the UserID will always be associated with the correct Thumbnail, Username, Email, etc.?

Comment: I think it's hard to "guarantee" anything in the HTML ecosystem, you have lots of different browsers implementing things and there are always corner cases. The spec talks about order here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1. You should test this, and if you want to be in the safe side perhaps include some numeric suffix in the field names.

Comment: After some testing then I also noticed that if I have different places with same field names (e.g. input with name="email" outside the range loop) then the data has a very high chance of getting mixed together (which of course should be no surprise), but it seems to work across all major browsers as long as the input names are unique for the rangeloop.. I'll probably look into adding the suffix later.. thanks again for everything <3